# How to switch Firefox channel to Stable?

Tags: firefox

I have switched to the Beta channel in my Firefox some time ago. Now I want the stable channel back. Unfortunately it is missed from http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/channel/

My FF:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For some reason they [decided to get rid of the channel-switching feature](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=659972).

Somebody explains how to switch back on the forums: http://support.mozilla.com/ca/questions/837315#answer-203401

Basically, I think you can just download and run the stable version installer, without having to uninstall anything.

Comment: The channel switcher was removed because it was found that most people that switch between the channels end up having parallel installations anyway - ie the previous system was "better". It's fairly easy to make multiple installs coexist with a little planning - see also http://superuser.com/questions/226498/how-can-i-install-both-firefox-3-6-and-firefox-4-beta

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to uninstall Firefox, if it asks about deleting your profile then answer "no", and then reinstall the version that you want.

I've done this before and suffered no ill effects...

Answer (score 2):

**You can't** (without reinstalling Firefox). The devs accidentally screwed us over—made a big deal about how easy it was to change channel (and back), then quietly removed that feature, leaving us stuck.