# How do I swith Firefox channel from beta to stable?

Tags: macos, firefox, browser, osx-yosemite

I did the mistake to try Firefox beta a while back. Now it's nagging me all the time about updates. I've tried the solution given [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/310221/how-to-switch-firefox-channel-to-stable), but to no help.

How do I get off the beta channel when on a Mac?

I'm on FF 36.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest Firefox Stable.
2. Drag your existing Firefox application to the trash.
3. Install the stable version you just downloaded.

As far as I know, your firefox profile (bookmarks, etc.) is *not* deleted when you perform the above. Still, if you want to be safe, backup the things important to you first like bookmarks.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I'm still on the beta channel after the procedure above.